# Regex @ symbol and how it's used

Tags: php, regex

If this is answered somewhere I apologize I couldn't find it.   This is taken from the php reference for preg_match.

```
<?php
// get host name from URL
preg_match('@^(?:http://)?([^/]+)@i',
"http://www.php.net/index.html", $matches);
$host = $matches[1];

// get last two segments of host name
preg_match('/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/', $host, $matches);
echo "domain name is: {$matches[0]}\n";
?>
```

I understand all of this except the @^ and @i.  I've searched a ton of regex reference and don't see any mention of the @ symbol except as a delimiter and that is not the case here.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@` is being used in place of the more common `/` because `/` is used within the pattern. It just allows the pattern to be more readable without having to escape it.

Picture the following (same pattern):

```
@^(?:http://)?([^/]+)@i
/^(?:http:\/\/)?(^\/]+)/i
```

And the `i`, as others have mentioned, makes the pattern CasE InsEnSAtive.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Appreciate the fast answer.

Answer (score 3):

`@` *is* the delimiter here. The `^` after the first `@` indicates that the match should start at the begining of the string, and the `i` after the is a switch to indicate that the regex is case-insensitive.

Any non-alphanumeric character can be used as a delimiter. The reason the author chose the `@` delimiter instead of the more standard `/`, is so that the slashes in the regex don't have to be escaped.

---

Your regex is equivalent to the following:

```
'/^(?:http:\/\/)?([^\/]+)/i'
```

Answer (score 1):

`@` as delimiter *is* the case here.  There is nothing special about `@^` or `@i`.  The symbols `@`, `^`, and `i` are all separate and indicate:

1. The regex delimiter (could be any other non-alphanumeric character or combination of `{}`)
2. The start of the line
3. The case-insensitive modifier